# Equally spacing radio buttons with width in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, html-table, radio-button

I have a group of radio buttons that I want to be equally spaced and centered under column headers. These buttons use this css to do so:

```
.staiRadioButtons
{
    display: inline;
    width: 111px;
}
```

This works just fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari the buttons are not as wide and thus misalign. What is the proper way of equally spacing radio buttons in a table column?

The section of HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>1. I feel pleasant.</td>
  <td><span id="spryradio1">
    <label>
      <input name="pleasant" type="radio" class="staiRadioButtons" id="pleasant_0" value="4" />
      <input name="pleasant" type="radio" class="staiRadioButtons" id="pleasant_1" value="3" />
      <input name="pleasant" type="radio" class="staiRadioButtons" id="pleasant_2" value="2" />
      <input name="pleasant" type="radio" class="staiRadioButtons" id="pleasant_3" value="1" />
    </label>
    <span class="radioRequiredMsg">Please make a selection.</span></span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.staiRadioButtons
{
    float:left;
    width: 111px;
}
```

Comment: No such luck. It doesn't affect the display at all; the buttons are still left aligned in Safari only.

Comment: That's not working either. I've tried inline, block, inline-block, and adjusting the width of the button class. None of these have an effect on the alignment of the radio buttons in Safari.